# How is the first Friedmann equation derived from Einstein's field equations?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, cosmology, metric-tensor, curvature

I see that Friedmann's first Equation (for flat space) is:
$$\left(\frac{\dot{a}}{a}\right)^2=\frac{8\pi G}{3}\rho.$$
And I know that Einstein's equation, just considering the time-time component is:
$$R_{00}-\frac{1}{2}g_{00}R=8\pi G T_{00}.$$
And I know that $T_{00}$ in the tensor is $\rho$, so we get:
$$R_{00}-\frac{1}{2}g_{00}R=8\pi G\rho.$$
Could someone please fill in the missing steps?  How do we arrive at:
$$R_{00}-\frac{1}{2}g_{00}R=3\left(\frac{\dot{a}}{a}\right)^2~?$$

Comment: I never found a solution filling in the missing steps. At best, textbooks (and I have at least five) just seem to leave this as an exercise. I have given a complete derivation of the Friedmann equation in my third book, for the case with curved space and cosmological constant, but it takes six pages of calculation, so I can't give an answer here.

Comment: @CharlesFrancis -  Are you available for a conversation in the h-bar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a typical example where a Newtonian derivation is much simpler and quicker, and gives the same answer. Which you can easily find online.

But if you want to do this from within GR, then you have to work out the Ricci tensor entry $R_{00}$, the Ricci scalar $R$, and the metric entry $g_{00}$:

- $g_{00} = 1$;
- $R_{00}$:
  $$ R_{00} = R^m_{tmt} = R^r_{rtr} + R^\theta_{t\theta t} + R^\phi_{t\phi t} = -3 \frac{\ddot a}{a},$$
  where each Riemann tensor depends on the Christoffel symbols (listed for instance in [section C](http://diposit.ub.edu/dspace/bitstream/2445/59759/1/TFG-Arnau-Romeu-Joan.pdf) here);
- $R$:
  $$R = g^{ik}R_{ik} = -6\frac{\ddot a}{a} - 6\left ( \frac{\dot a}{a} \right )^2 - 6\frac{1}{k^2a^2},$$ where $k^{-2}=0$ for flat space.

So putting it all together:
$$ R_{00}  -\frac{1}{2}Rg_{00} = -3\frac{\ddot a}{a}+3\frac{\ddot a}{a} + 3\left ( \frac{\dot a}{a} \right )^2.$$

Hence:
$$3\left ( \frac{\dot a}{a} \right )^2 = 8\pi G\rho, $$
$$ \Rightarrow \left ( \frac{\dot a}{a} \right )^2 = \frac{8\pi G}{3}\rho. $$

Comment: Worth noting that the RHS follows from the stress energy tensor of a perfect fluid.

Comment: Ah yes, good to point out that assumption.

Comment: *Which you can easily find online.*  I have no idea even what search terms I would use.  Any chance you could find one and post the link?  It'd be educational to see how it's done with Newtonian physics.

Comment: @GluonSoup http://astronomy.nmsu.edu/aklypin/AST616/SimpleDerivation.pdf

Comment: By “easily” I meant that it’s the derivation you would usually find. Fewer sources do the actual GR one. Most university lecture notes always go classical.

Comment: @SuperCiocia - Do you understand this derivation?  I can't read the handwriting and am trying to decode the step where the constant of integration is turned into the curvature term.  That is, how does $\frac{8 \pi G}{3}\rho R^2+A$ and $B=A\left(\frac {g}{R}\right)^2$ become $\frac{k c^2}{a^2}$ in the GR version.

Comment: @GluonSoup $B = A(\color{red}{a}/R)^2$ but I agree they're being a bit cavalier with the maths because essentially they know what they should end up with. Maybe look at eq. 25 [here](http://diposit.ub.edu/dspace/bitstream/2445/59759/1/TFG-Arnau-Romeu-Joan.pdf) which is also derived with Newtonian mechanics. Maybe that's more understandable.

Comment: And what's the $R$ in this part anyway?  Shouldn't a Radius of Curvature (also $R$) be making its way into the equation by this time?

Comment: $R$ is the radius of the sphere, planet or star. You will not have a curvature term $k$ here since you're in classical mechanics. But they do get this $B$ term. And they write that in terms of the density parameter $\Omega_0$ which also appears in GR. There is an $\Omega_0$ associated with the cosmological constant (constant), with the radiation density ($\propto a^{-4}$), with dark+baryonic matter ($\propto a^{-3}$), and with the 'spatial curvature density', which goes as $\propto a^{-2}$. So here they "deus ex machina" it and associate it with the curvature because it's $ \propto a^{-2}$.

Answer (score 1):

$$\Gamma_{ab}{}^{c} = \frac{1}{2}g^{cd}\left(g_{ad, b} + g_{bd,a} - g_{ab,d}\right)$$

$$R_{ab} = \partial_{c}\Gamma_{ab}{}^{c} - \partial_{a}\Gamma_{bc}{}^{c} + \Gamma_{ab}{}^{c}\Gamma_{ce}{}^{e} - \Gamma_{ad}{}^{c}\Gamma_{bc}{}^{d}$$

So, given a metric, you can compute any christoffel symbol, and given any christoffel symbol, you can calculate the ricci tensor.  Just turn the crank and compute $R_{00}$ and $R$